# When you want to ensure someone that what they are looking for has not been lost and it is right here and you'll find it

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Please imagine you've lost your wallet and have looked for it everywhere in the house.Your mom wants to help you, but she notices that you're getting angry and wants to ensure you that it is in the house and somehow tell ask you to keep your cool. There is a saying in my mother language which can be used here by the mom! I would be thankful if you could let me know if it works in natural English. If not, then please let me know what shall the mom say instead:

> - It’s somewhere staring you right in the face.

P.S. This is a translation.

Comment: *Assure*, not *ensure*.

Comment: "It's (somewhere) right under your nose" is an idiom somewhat similar to that expression.

Comment: Another common phrase is "[It's around here somewhere.](https://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/something-is-around-here-somewhere)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's staring you in the face" is an idiom, but I think it's used more commonly for something abstract than for a physical object: a solution to a problem, a resemblance, a possible course of action.

As MorganFR says, "It's right under your nose" is more common for a physical object.